# Optimize user experience in Salesforce Service Console

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, performance

today I have a bit odd question (since it will not be code related) ;)
did any of you happend to know good tool to optimize user experience in Salesforce Service Console?
I mean something like ClickTale, Crazy Egg, Megalytic or Mixpanel?
Also it would be good to know if any of those tools work well with SF.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Can you be more specific? Did you look on the app exchange? Do you have anything in particular you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: Subject is exactly what I am looking for. After design and develop phase when console is up and running I would like to be able to track where user clicks and type - to rearrange console layout to better fit users needs / make their work more eficient.